# Angular2 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined in (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-http

I'm getting the following error:

```
angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of null in [


{{ product.Id }}
 in ProductEditComponent@0:68]
```

thrown with:

```
//Product-edit.component.ts:

import {Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { IProduct } from './product'
import { ProductService } from './product.service'
import { RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  template:`<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight ecommerce"> 
              {{ product.Id }}
            </div>`, 
})
export class ProductEditComponent{
    product: IProduct = null;
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams, private _productService: ProductService){

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProduct(this._routeParams.get('id'))
            .subscribe(
                product => this.product = product,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);


    }

}
```

ProductService:

```
getProduct(id: string): Observable<IProduct> {
    return this._http.get(this._baseUrl + this._getProductUrl + '/' + id)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Response from server:

```
{"Id":"34d4efcy6","ExternalId":null,"UserId":"testing","ProductProvider":null,"Title":"Flaska vin","Desc":null,"MinDeliveryTime":null,"MaxDeliveryTime":null,"FreightCost":null,"Brand":null}
```

What am I messing up?

Comment: Do you get any error in `this.handleError`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your component, you're initializing `product` to null, and then referencing `product.Id` in your template. The error occurs when Angular tries to draw your template initially, *before* your async call returns - at which point `product` is still null, thus the error: `Cannot read property 'Id' of null`.

The most immediate solution is to use the [Elvis operator](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0), which Angular provides for situations precisely like this. You'd use it by replacing `{{ product.Id }}` with `{{ product?.Id }}` in your template.

That said, you're likely to run into change detection problems with this approach, and in general you'll be much better off with an approach like:

```
export class ProductEditComponent{
  product: Observable<IProduct>; //product is an Observable
  errorMessage: string;
  constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams, private _productService: ProductService){
     //product is always defined because you instantiate it in the ctor
     this._productService.getProduct(this._routeParams.get('id'));
  }
```

You'd then use `{{(product | async).Id }}` in place of `{{product.Id}}` in your template, leveraging [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html) to let angular handle the dirtywork of subscribing and updating the UI as needed for you.